# Ubuntu 12.04 with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I have two monitors which where recognized in Ubuntu 12.04 after the installation was completed but now, after installing the ATI driver, one of my monitors is shown as "Laptop".
Everytime I try to switch "Mirror displays" off I get an error saying that the resolution is not supported.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed the proprietary ATI driver, you have to use the tool AMDCCLE to configure your monitors. Just search "AMD" in the dash, and then you can change the resolution there.

Comment: (I don't have access to my ATI machine, otherwise I'd add screenshots.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to mirror displays, they must both support any one resolution. Set both monitors to the highest common resolution, and then try to mirror the displays again. However, the highest common resolution may be as low as 800x600 or even 640x480, which is not a good resolution for easily using newer versions of Ubuntu.